# Laravel 5 Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation, laravel-authentication

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse

I have my Register controller that checks if a membership id exists in a separate member table before creating a user. For existing membership Id, it works fine but when a user enters a non-existing Id I need it to redirect to the same register page with the error message. But all I get is the error above. Please note that I am using

`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable`

in my user model and also my `fillables` array is correct.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'membership_id' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:users'],

        ]);
    }


  protected function create(array $data)
    {   
        $member = Member::where('member', '=', Input::get('membership_id'))->first();
        if($member){
            return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'membership_id' => $data['membership_id'],
        ]);
        }elseif (!$member) {
            return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['message' =>'Membership Id does not exist']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Member class like this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Member extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
}
```